# Existence of basis in both finite dimensional vector space and its dual such that their interaction has some orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(X,\left|.\right|)$ be a finite dimensional normed vector space (the norm might not be induced from some inner product). Show that there exists a basis $x_1,x_2,...x_n$ in X and a basis $l_1,l_2,...l_n$ in $X^*$ such that:

(1) $|x_i| = 1$ for $i=1,...n$

(2) $|l_j| = 1$ for $j=1,...n$

(3) $l_j(x_i) = \delta_{ij}$ for $\forall i, j$

Comment: X basis exists by taking any basis and scaling so they are all unit norm. Take 3 to be the definition of l, show they are linearly independent. I'm unsure what 2 means. What norm is used in the dual space?

Comment: The norm on dual space is $| l |= sup_{|x| \leq 1} |l(x)|$

Answer (score 1):

Take any normalised basis $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ of $X$. Define $l_j$ to be the linear map sending $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\alpha_ix_i$ to $\alpha_j$. Then the $l_j$ are normalised (clearly $l_j(x_j) = 1$, and anything else in $B(0,1)$ has $x_j$-component at most $1$), and $l_j(x_i) = \delta_{ij}$, as required.

Comment: But (2) is not satisfied yet. For a vector space without defined norm, why everything in B(0,1) has $x_j$ component less than 1? And $l_{\infty}$ is the counter example, take (1,1/2) and (-1,1/2) as the basis, then (0,1) has component 2 on both basis directions.

Comment: (2) is satisfied: I'm assuming you're using the dual norm (because what else makes sense?) and the thing that I put in the brackets is a proof of (2) for that norm. Your vector space *does* have a defined norm, and that's the norm in which I took the ball, and also the norm in which I normalised $x_j$, so the triangle inequality gives the statement about the coordinates immediately. For your example: $(0,1)$ has component $1$ in both basis directions: you are correct that I mean "less than or equal to", rather than "less than", though.